# What is the root directory of a site deployed on heroku?

Tags: python, django

The Root page of the site is:  amaze2020.herokuapp.com
I need to save a verification .txt file into the root directory of amaze2020.herokuapp.com.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

For Herkou, unless specified otherwise, it should always be "/app".